# Why is my asp.net button.text value not the appropriate value when the button.click function is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this asp.net button that I programmatically placed inside the header row of an asp.net table. When clicked, the button calls a function that hides or shows the rows (not the header row) of the table.

```
    private void Hide_or_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button button = sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button;
    Table table = (Table)button.Parent.Parent.Parent;


    if (button.Text == "Hide")
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }

        button.Text = "Show";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows[i].Visible = true;
        }
        button.Text = "Hide";
    }
}
```

When I call the function the first time, to hide the table, everything seems to work perfectly. But, when I then click the button to show the table, even though in my browser, the button says "Show", when the program enters the function, the button.text is equal to "Hide". It seems that the text is changing on the client side, but not on the server side. Because of this, it never gets the the 'else' part of the function.

Comment: Do you set the text back to `"Hide"` in `Page_Load`?

Comment: show how you create this button and assign its Text

Comment: Does it work if you move the button outside the table, f.e. by adding it directly to the page for testing purposes? When you say "programmatically", where (in the page's life-cycle) do you create this button, do you always (re)create it on every postback?

Comment: @David Yup, that was the issue. I didn't even realize that Page_Load was called again when I hit the button. Thank you!

Comment: All three of your answers are helpful. I didn't realize that the Page_Load function was called. Because it is called, the button is recreated and gets the original text value of "Hide". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this as an answer (from the comments above) to help future visitors...

If you're setting the text in `Page_Load` then that would over-ride what you're trying to accomplish.  Remember that `Page_Load` (among others) gets called on *every* request, not just the initial one.  And [it's called *before* your handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx).  So by setting the `.Text` property in `Page_Load`, your order of events becomes:

- Initial page load, set text to "Show" in `Page_Load`
- Click the show button, set text to "Show" in `Page_Load`
- Handle click event, set text to "Hide" in `Hide_or_Show`
- Click the hide button, set text to "Show" in `Page_Load`
- Handle click event... text is now "Show" (error condition you're seeing)

The quick and dirty solution in that case would be to wrap that part of your `Page_Load` logic in a conditional so it only happens on an initial load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    button.Text = "Show";
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. It definitely helps to see the whole process written out like this!

Answer (score 3):

Why use the text of the button?  Why not just use

```
private void Hide_or_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Table table = (Table)button.Parent.Parent.Parent;

for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Rows[i].Visible = !table.Rows[i].Visible;
    }
}
```

Then you don't even need the if statement.

Comment: That would definitely be a more compact way of doing it! My problem, however, was that my page_load function was being called. So the table.row.visible was always being set back to true, and the button.text was always being set back to hide. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll be using this. XD